# Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'. How can I fix this? Need to get blob image from input file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I hit my submit button on my page I get the following **error**:

```
Something has gone wrong. Action failed: c$TestComponent$controller$pictures [TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsDataURL' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'.] Failing descriptor: {c$TestComponent$controller$pictures}. Please try again.
```

I know it's due to my fileUpload feature inside my **HTML and JSS**. I'm not sure why this is happening or how to fix it.

**My HTML:**

```
    <div id="wrapper">       
 <input id="fileUpload" type="file" onchange ="{!c.pictures}" multiple="5" />
 <br/>
       <div id="image-holder"/>
 </div>
```

**My JS:**

```
pictures : function()
{
    if (typeof (FileReader) != "undefined") {

        var image_holder = $("#image-holder");
        image_holder.empty();

        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            $("<img />", {
                "src": e.target.result,
                "class": "thumb-image"
            }).appendTo(image_holder);

        }
        image_holder.show();
        reader.readAsDataURL($("#fileUpload")[0].files[0]);
    } else {
        alert("This browser does not support FileReader.");
    }
},
```

Any ideas? If someone can show me how to solve this that would help. Been working on this for hours and can't come to a conclusion.